# VB .NET Array list of MenuItems

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

i would like to collect in VB .NET some MenuItems in a list of controls to easily manage many of them. The following code works using CheckBox for instance:

```
dim myMenuList() as Control
myMenuList = New Control() {MenuItem1, MenuItem2, MenuItem3, MenuItem4}
```

... but using it in this way, with MenuItem, Visual Studio give me this error:

```
It is impossible to convert from 'System.Windows.Forms.MenuItem' to 'System.Windows.Forms.Controls'
```

What's wrong with my code? I Thought that MenuItem is also a Control.
How can i make a list of MenuItems?

Thanks in advance,

Bye
hwktest

Comment: MenuItems inherit from `System.Windows.Forms.Menu` not Control, so you need to change the array type: `dim myMenuList() as MenuItem`  Of course they exist perfectly fine in the menu itself without new references in your code.  Also that is an Array not an ArrayList

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since MenuItem is not based on Control but on the Windows.Forms.Menu Class which is based on the Component Class, your best bet would to be to find a common ancestor, in this case it would be the [`Component Class`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.component(v=vs.110).aspx).

Try something like this.

```
Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Class Form1

    Public Sub New()

        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()

        ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.

        Dim MenuItem1 As New MenuItem
        Dim MenuItem2 As New MenuItem
        Dim MenuItem3 As New MenuItem
        Dim MenuItem4 As New MenuItem
        Dim button1 As New Button
        Dim myMenuList() As Component = New Component() {MenuItem1, MenuItem2, MenuItem3, MenuItem4, button1}
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Well, just make it a MenuItem()

Comment: @HansPassant that would be ideal, but it sounds like he was wanting to have it in an array of other controls, I probably read way to much into his question.

Comment: @MarkHall thank you very much for both explanation and code! This is what i was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

> ***What's wrong with my code? I Thought that MenuItem is also a Control.***

*MenuItem* is not derived from *Control*. Look at the inheritance hierarchy and you'll see that the last common class is  `Component`..

*[Control:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control(v=vs.110).aspx#inheritanceContinued)*

- System.Object

  - System.MarshalByRefObject

    - System.ComponentModel.Component

      - System.Windows.Forms.Control

*[MenuItem:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.menuitem(v=vs.110).aspx)*

- System.Object

  - System.MarshalByRefObject

    - System.ComponentModel.Component

      - System.Windows.Forms.Menu

        - System.Windows.Forms.MenuItem

> ***How can i make a list of MenuItems?***

Like this:

```
Dim myMenuList As New List(Of MenuItem) From {MenuItem1, MenuItem2, MenuItem3, MenuItem4}
```

Or an array if you prefer:

```
Dim myMenuList As MenuItem() = {MenuItem1, MenuItem2, MenuItem3, MenuItem4}
```